# Can't update labels in custom UIView in xib file

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard, xib, nib

I've designed a custom `UIView` in a xib file.
This custom `UIView` containts multiple labels.

I have a Swift class with the exact name that is set as the owner of this xib file. I've connected the labels to the file's owner class using IBOutlets.

A sample outlet connection looks like this:
[image]

The file's owner code looks like this. The contentView outlet is an outlet from the parent view of my custom view.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var seatsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initSubviews()

    }
    func initSubviews() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: nil)
        nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = bounds
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
    func updateView() {

        //...
        self.seatsLabel.text = "10 seats"
        //nothing happens here, even if I do this operation on the main queue  
    }

}
```

The respective view does show up with the default values. But when I want to change something, it does not react. I guess that the outlets are somehow broken. I've used this view in a storyboard file by dragging a UIView in and setting ints class to `MyView`. Can someone tell me what I have to change in my code so that I can change the label's text? I haven't quite understood how to deal with xib files.

Comment: What have you tired to solve this issue? Have you set a breakpoint? Does seatsLabel exist in the updateView Method?

Comment: Does `updateView` get called somewhere?

Comment: I've set multiple break points and the method does get called. So from my side, everything should be fine, but still there is somewhere something wrong.